# Twillio Programmable Video

Tags: webrtc, twilio, video-processing

Is it possible with the Programmable Video API from Twilio to build something that resembles the Google Hangouts functionality in terms of how it focuses on the person talking automatically?

I don't see any examples or notes about this in their documentation and the github for this doesn't seem to be frequented that much.

Would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: I don't use Twilio or WebRTC but in general you detect which connection (user) is speaking... Either check volume (is it above minimum amount threshold?) or check for source of incoming audio data bytes, and focus on that connection/user.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can build that sort of thing, however it is currently out of scope for the Video SDK itself.

I haven't done this before, but I'd start by looking into analysing the audio coming from each participant in the chat. You can actually create audio sources from an existing `<video>` or `<audio>` element. In the case of Twilio Video, each track is created as a separate element, so you want to look for `<audio>` elements and use them:

```
var audioElements = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
audioElements.forEach(audio => {
  var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  // create audio analyser, analyse volume in audio
})
```

You want to use the Web Audio API to then analyse all the remote tracks and work out which is currently making the most noise for a sustained period of time and switch to that one. [This blog post may help with the analysis](http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound). I've not seen anything that will help with the selection, but hopefully you can work it out from there.

Let me know if this helps at all.